# Under which situation must a signal be defined as a reg?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

For example, in this code. The answer is none of the signals **must** be declared as `reg`. So, if this is truly the case, then what is the use of this code? I think the question's ambiguity lies in **must**. I think that in this case, the signals `r1`, `out_reg` and `out_but` should be declared as a `reg` and `w1`, `out` should be declared as `wire`.

```
module temp(...);
...
assign w1 = a ^ b;
always @ *
begin
  r1 = a & b;
  out_reg = a | w1;
  out_bus = 5'd25;
end
assign out = r1;
endmodule
```

Or, this is just a question for test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the old version of Verilog (IEEE Std 1364), continuous assignments using the `assign` keyword would typically be to signals declared as `wire`, whereas procedural assignments, inside an `always` block, for example, would be to signals declared as `reg`.  This compiles:

```
module temp(
    input a, b, output out
);
wire w1;
reg r1, out_reg, out_bus;
assign w1 = a ^ b;
always @ *
begin
  r1 = a & b;
  out_reg = a | w1;
  out_bus = 5'd25;
end
assign out = r1;
endmodule
```

However, this is no longer necessary under the current version of Verilog known as SystemVerilog (IEEE Std 1800).  You may still use `wire` and `reg` as above if you like, or you can use `reg` for all in your code.  This compiles:

```
module temp(
    input a, b, output out
);
reg w1, r1, out_reg, out_bus;
assign w1 = a ^ b;
always @ *
begin
  r1 = a & b;
  out_reg = a | w1;
  out_bus = 5'd25;
end
assign out = r1;
endmodule
```

The `logic` keyword introduced in SystemVerilog can be used in place of `reg`.

This all depends on how well your simulation tool adheres to the Std.